# C++ memoization - Fibonacci function - map verus vector container execution time

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, memoization

I'm trying to learn memoization in C++ and have implemented two Fibonacci functions using `map` and `vector`. I've submitted them to the Coursera data structures course. The `vector` implementation fails due to taking too much time and the `map` passes OK. As both implement memoization could anybody suggest why one fails and the other passes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int fibonacci_fast_vector(int n)
{
    vector <int> cache;

    if(n<=1) {
        return n;
    }
    else if ((unsigned)n >= cache.size()) {
            cache.resize(n+1);
        }

    if(cache[n] != 0) {
        return cache[n];
    }

    // otherwise
    int ret=fibonacci_fast_vector(n-1)+fibonacci_fast_vector(n-2);
    cache[n]=ret;
    return ret;
}


int fibonacci_fast_map(int n)
{
    static map<int,int>memo;

    if(n<=1)
        return n;

    if(memo.count(n)>0) { /*if it is in the map return the element*/
        return memo[n];
    }

    // otherwise
    int ret=fibonacci_fast_map(n-1)+fibonacci_fast_map(n-2);
    memo[n]=ret;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    std::cout << fibonacci_fast_map(n) << '\n';
    std::cout << fibonacci_fast_vector(n) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your vector isn't static.  That makes it behave completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that your vector is not static. Put a static keyword or declare it in the global scope. This will reduce the huge performance time because you avoid many `news` and `deletes`. Also you can create with some initial size vector if you know the probable size for the same performance reason.

Answer (score 4):

In this code:

```
int fibonacci_fast_vector(int n)
{
    vector <int> cache;
```

your vector is not static so you create a new vector on every function call, so your "memoization" not only fails to work but actually makes it slower.

Btw this code:

```
if(memo.count(n)>0) { /*if it is in the map return the element*/
    return memo[n];
}
```

is unnecessary inefficient - you are doing 2 lookups in case data is there or 2 lookups if it is not, which is significantly expensive operation on a map. You should use something like this:

```
auto p = memo.emplace(n,0);
if( p.second ) // data was not there
    p.first->second = fibonacci_fast_map(n-1)+fibonacci_fast_map(n-2);

return p.first->second;
```